# How do I test dependabot before merging config

Tags: github, dependabot

Is there a way to test that dependabot is working as expected before merging it to my repo?

I work on a pretty large team and I want to make sure I can test the functionality before merging. I have a branch created with a PR open to our develop branch. Is there a way to make sure the PR to update the dependencies is created and the reviewers I have set are added?

Comment: Not valid for you, if you work with a big team, but if you are an admin of the repo and have the flexibility, you can switch temporarily the "default" branch to the one where you have your changes, and later on switch back to the original default branch

Answer (score 7):

Solutions that previously worked include:

1. The GitHub action https://github.com/marocchino/validate-dependabot
2. A GitHub solution previously located at https://dependabot.com/docs/config-file/validator/

Both are currently not working:

- GitHub says they are working on the issue at https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/4605
- The validate-dependabot issue is tracked at https://github.com/marocchino/validate-dependabot/issues/233

Comment: validate-dependabot has been fixed in November, here's a user with recent workflow runs: https://github.com/t3rn/t3rn/actions/workflows/dependabot-validate.yml
That said, I'd prefer an "official" solution built into dependabot 

Comment: (I do have to add that it did not find the specific error I had... username and password are required in registries but validator did not complain about is...)